# Trouble with #lang in Racket v7.0

Tags: racket

I just installed DrRacket v7.0 (Windows 10) and am working through Beautiful Racket (https://beautifulracket.com/stacker/intro.html). When I try to run the sample code in the intro:

```
#lang reader stacker-demo/stacker
4
8
+
3
*
```

I get the following error message: *read-syntax: `#lang` not enabled*. I have installed the beautiful-racket package described in Setup and can verify that it was successfully installed. I also followed the instructions for the setting br as the default language and Dr­Racket starts with **Language: br, with debugging**. I tried looking through their built-in documentation (which is very thorough) but couldn't find anything related to this specific error.

Comment: To be clear, that code needs to go in the definitions window, not the interactions window (aka the REPL).

Comment: @AlexisKingThank you! The code snippet works correctly when I copy and paste it into the definitions window.